# How to write the type hint for an argument that can be of either class A or class B?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to put an object as the argument value of the function.
`anything_object` can be A class or B class.

```
class A:
    name: str

class B:
    phone: int

class ObjectInfo
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    def getObjectFieldName(self, anything_object: ?) -> list:
        return dir(anything_object)
```

Comment: [`Union[A, B]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)? [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any)?

Comment: btw that would be a syntax error, you will have to use `@dataclass` for that.. but as jonsharpe said, you can use `typing.Union[type1, type2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Union` to specify multiple type hintings (for both, arguments and return type). You will have to import `Union` from standard library `typing`.

```
from typing import Union

class A:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name

class B:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name 


class ObjectInfo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass 

    def method(self, object:Union[A, B]=None) -> list:
        return dir(object)

obj = ObjectInfo()
print(obj.method())
```

**[External Links]**
More on type hinting : https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html